Filter a new array which index is divided by two
I have a array of number. I want to filter a new array which have element which index is divided by two
Example:
let arr = [1, 4, 5, 2, 8, 9, 7, 10];

I want filter a 2 new arrays like:
let odd = [1, 5, 8, 7];
let even = [4, 2, 9, 7];

I've tried like this but it didn't work
const odd = arr.filter((i) => {
  return arr[i % 2 === 0];
})


How exactly didn't your attempt work? Was there an error? Did it give an unexpected result? You seem to be using a boolean as an index with i % 2 === 0.

Also, for the filter method, you simply want to return a boolean, which determines whether that particular item is included. so something like return (i % 2 === 0)

Why is 8 in odd, 7 and 9 in even, and why is 10 missing completely?

@RoryMcCrossan a guess would be that it's by index, not by value and the missing 10 is an unhelpful typo in the second list which has 7.

@fdomn-m it is by index - that was already specified in the beginning of the question. But there are two unhelpful typos - the 7 which with 4, 2, and 9, as you note, and the second one is that odd contains the even indexes, and even contains the odd indexes.

I understood that you would like the values, but in fact it is the index, to do this, simply receive a second parameter in the filter function, which is the index of the current element:
arr.filter((e, i) => { return i % 2 === 0; });

previous answer:
I believe the answer is this:
arr.filter((e) => {return e % 2 == 0})

when you use the filter function the iteration element is the array position value.
In your case, the condition:
i % 2 === 0

returns a boolean value and tries to find a value in the array at that position, so it doesn't work.

This doesn't separate by index but by value.

You are right, to separate by index, just receive a second parameter in the filter function, which is the index of the current element: arr.filter((e, i) => { return i % 2 === 0; })
